# SQL Query to identify missing Event (record)

Tags: sql, join

I have a table events where I store
Cust-ID, Event-ID, Time

My Events are fixed with IDs as EV1, EV2, EV3, EV4, EV5 (in sequential order but the sequence of EV2 and EV3 can be repeated and also that EV3 cannot happen without EV2)

I want to have a query where I can find the details of Cust-ID and the time where EV2 was missed i.e., EV3 was recorded without a preceding EV2.
For e.g., if there is data like the table below, I want to identify the output as 1, EV3, 10:30 as EV2 is missing.

```
------------------------------------
| Cust_ID    | Event_ID |time      |
------------------------------------
| 1          | EV1      | 10:29    |
------------------------------------
| 1          | EV3      | 10:30    |
------------------------------------
| 1          | EV4      | 10:31    |
------------------------------------
| 1          | EV5      | 10:33    |
------------------------------------
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   Cust-Id, time
FROM 
   “Your-table”
WHERE
   EV2 IS NULL, EV3 IS NOT NULL
```

This should filter out the cust-id and time, where there is no value for EV2 but EV3 exists

Comment: EV2 and EV3 are not column names but values, So I can't compare them against null. If you see the sample table that I have pasted, it may help you understand